# passing arguments in rspec shared example

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am a bit new with Rspec.

Here is my problem

I have an example which could be shared

### shared example

```
RSpec.shared_examples "coupons_shared" do |arg1,email,coupon1,coupon2|
  it "present_coupons" do
    post_rest_url = "https://blahblahblah=" + "#{arg1}" + "&email=" + "#{email}"
    json_request = <<END_OF_MESSAGE
    [
"#{coupon1}",
"#{coupon2}"
    ]
END_OF_MESSAGE
    header = {:accept => "application/json",:content_type => "application/json"}
    resp = RestClient.post(post_rest_url, json_request, header)
    json_obj = JSON.parse(resp)
    expect(json_obj[0]["ccode"]).to include("#{coupon1}")
    expect(json_obj[0]["ccode"]).to include("#{coupon2}")
  end
end
```

shared example file location is in \spec\support\shared_examples

In the actual spec file I have an example which gets the coupon and then need to present using the shared example

```
describe "enrol_cust" do
  cust_id = '1'
  coupons = []
  header_basic_auth = {:accept => "application/json",:content_type => "application/json"}
  random_no = (rand(999) + 10)
  random_no = random_no.to_s
  email = "johndoe" + "#{random_no}" + "@gmail.com"
  st = 1111
  st = st.to_i
  before(:each) do
    @dob = 20.years.ago(Date.today).strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
  end

  it "enrol_cust" do
    post_rest_url = "https://blahblah?st=" + "#{st}"
    json_request = <<END_OF_MESSAGE
{
"email": "#{email}",
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"date_of_birth": "#{@dob}",
}
END_OF_MESSAGE
    header = header_basic_auth
    resp = RestClient.post(post_rest_url, json_request, header)
    json_obj = JSON.parse(resp)
    cust_id = json_obj["cid"]
  end
# above example gets customer id

it "get_list" do
    get_rest_url = "https://blahblah=" + "#{cust_id}" + "&st=" + "#{st}"
    header = header_basic_auth
    resp = RestClient.get(get_rest_url, header)
    json_obj = JSON.parse(resp)
    coupons = json_obj.collect {|x| x["cccode"]}
end
# above example gets coupons
# I have tried printing out the coupons and I can see the correct coupons in this example

include_examples "coupons_shared" ,"#{st}","#{email}","#{coupons[0]}","#{coupons[1]}"
```

When I try to pass the parameters, st and email is passed correctly. However, coupons[0] and coupons[1] is always passed as ""

I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: I think it would work if you moved the code out of the `it "get_list"` block and into the `describe` block. Basically each `it` block has its own context, and it's not typical to share their results with other `it` examples.

Comment: Try to reduce example. If you think passing arguments doesn’t work, write a simple example that only pass arguments. It looks like you’re using it right, but passing empty strings

Answer (score 0):

To pass an argument to a shared example, wrap the variable inside the example block (without listing them as you have as arguments in the example):

```
RSpec.shared_examples "coupons_shared" do
  ...code that includes your variables coupon1, coupon2 etc..
end
```

```
include_examples "coupons_shared" do
  coupon1 = coupons[0]
  ...and so on (also works with let)...
  let(:coupon1) { coupons[0] }
end
```

I would also strongly suggest that you stub out the HTTP requests so they aren't hitting an actual server every time you run your tests and consider using FactoryBot (or fixtures if that's your preference) to clean up a lot of the variable assignments.